# I am having to improve my ASP.NET, should I just jump to MVC rather than Webforms?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

I know many have asked the MVC vs Webforms question many times. My question is slightly different in that I am currently updating my skills from ASP.NET2/VB.NET to ASP.NET4/C#. I am seriously thinking that I should perhaps not waste time in upgrading my Webforms skills which are Okish, but instead put the effort into starting again with MVC. I keep looking at all the properties of ASP.NET server controls and sigh !!! I do see the benefit in just focussing on web technologies such as JS, CSS and now JQuery and CSS3.

I would be interested in your thoughts?

Comment: Why not sharpen your skills on both?  Don't focus on specific products or specific frameworks.  Learn the fundamental differences, the pros and cons of both, etc.  There's a _lot_ of overlap between WebForms and MVC in the grand scheme of .NET as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are doing a clean-slate here.  You are changing languages and technologies.  My advice would be to identify what you feel is the best technology going forward and learn that.  You are already committing to learning something new - make it the most valuable experience you can make it.

From my perspective, I would recommend MVC.  Personally I feel that this is the better platform to move forward on.  You will have to add quite a few auxiliary skills such as Razor, JQuery and all the rest but it will be worth it.  The bottom line though is that it is what is best for you.  If your environment is better served by Webforms, then that is the best choice for you.

Comment: At this point I am unsure as to what is the best environment. Yes I am starting afresh on 2 internet web applications which will use a lot of data access which will be LINQ/SQL Server and some LINQ/XML. Also I can see a port to mobile devices hence the interest in JQuery. I have also be told about Marcotte's Responsive design using Media Query. A number of years ago I designed an XSLT/XML framework for rendering pages. I think in hindsight these XSLT pages were views !!! This was post Classic ASP. Now we have Razor instead of XSLT. Perhaps I know more about MVC than I realise!!

Comment: Based on all of that, I would definitely recommend MVC.  If you don't mind being on the cutting edge, MVC4 is great.  It has some nice features around mobile devices.  If you are at all nervous about a beta release though, MVC3 still works very well.

Comment: Also I think at the moment it seems quite important to focus on the important technologies for each layer ie HTML5/JQuery/CSS3 and then App services in the application layer such as LINQ, Workflow or whatever. However the sting is that I do not want to double my dev time!!!

Comment: What are the advantages of switching over to Razor - genuinely curious :)

Comment: Razor makes life AWESOME! (was that over the top?)  You mix your C# code into your HTML page with ease so you can get the best of both worlds without complications.  It makes your HTML cleaner and easier to understand.  I could go on...

Comment: But doesn't mixing code and markup make it more difficult? (kinda like old ASP)?

Comment: Thanks all. I found your feedback to be hugely useful. As a new user I was surprised to have this question closed since I have been greatly helped. Thanks.

Comment: @IrishChieftain Check out ScottGu's announcement of Razor for some great examples of how Razor is an improvement - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx

Comment: @EdB - The reason your question was closed was because you weren't asking a specific question about a code problem.  An open-ended question can be very subjective and it isn't one that SO wants to have here.  I chose to see your question as technical and introductory but others obviously disagreed.  In any event, I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Six months ago I changed jobs.  I was previously working at a large company that was still on .NET 2.0, VB.NET and ASP.NET WebForms.  I now work at a company that uses .NET 4.0, C# and ASP.NET MVC3.  So, I've been through this myself.

If you understand how the web works and want complete control over the client experience, MVC is the answer without a doubt.  At my previous job I would end up pulling my hair out because I hated how WebForms prevented me from creating a page with clean markup.  But, a lot of people don't know how HTTP, CSS, Javascript and HTML all fit together.  WebForms was a solution to that.  But, it's much more fun and performant to have complete control of what you sent to your customer/client.

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes I do understand how the web works but have become concerned that I am becoming divorced from it through the use of server controls etc. It seems so important to understand presentation design and how to implement it using what now seem defacto technologies such as JQuery etc. My only concern is the speed to develop and get going on this MVC approach. I guess the answer is bite the bullet and get going !!!